# DVD Drive Abnormally Noisy

Tags: dvd, noise

I have a DVD drive (HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GH22NS50 ATA) and when playing Music CDs or using data disks it makes quite a lot noise, is there anything I can do to reduce this or is it related to the speed? If so, can I slow the speed down?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the drive. They don't cost much these days.

Maybe you could reduce the speed for data transfers, but not for playing music.